# Use two databases in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, oracle, connection-string, tns

I have a Django 1.5 application with a SQLite or MySQL database. At the local server I have an Oracle database which I typically connect to with a connection string

> "TNS=TNS-name; UID=user; PWD=pwd;".

How is it possible to print data from the local Oracle database in my Django application? 
Actually, I want to transfer data from the Oracle database into my main SQLite/MySQL database.
 I've seen some tutorials how to use an Oracle database as main database source in a Django application, but I want to keep my main database source and just load some specific data from the Oracle database in a specific Django view.

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/  is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for, but the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/) seem to do a good job explaining it (if I interpreted it correctly).  In short, you need to add it to your list of databases in your settings file and create a router.  The lookup chain for databases is detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers).

Comment: I see it's possible to get a queryset from another db with `ModelName.objects.using('other').all()`, but I don't want to sync to this Oracle database at all; I just need to query some of the rows in it. I've been looking for a way to establish connection with a connection string, but I can't find it. I don't know if it's possible at all.

Comment: If you don't want to sync in Django then just install the Oracle Instant Client and cx_Oracle for Python and incorporate this in your application.